# Move constructors of STL containers in MSVC 2017 are not marked as noexcept

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2017

I am moving my project from VS2015 to VS2017, which of course does not go smoothly.

I am seeing strange compiler error that can be reproduced by the following code:

```
struct MoveOnly
{
    MoveOnly() {}
    MoveOnly(const MoveOnly&) = delete;
    MoveOnly& operator = (const MoveOnly&) = delete;
    MoveOnly(MoveOnly&&) = default;
    MoveOnly& operator = (MoveOnly&&) = default;
    bool operator == (const MoveOnly& rhs)const{return false;}
};
struct Hasher
{
    size_t operator()(const MoveOnly&)const{return 0;}
};
std::vector < std::unordered_map<MoveOnly, int, Hasher> > test;
test.emplace_back();
```

I can successfully compile this code with all compilers (gcc 7.2, clang 5.0.0, icc 18, as well as MSVC 2015). Please follow this link to see the test:
https://godbolt.org/g/uSqwDJ. On MSVC 2017 (19.10.25017), however there is an error that is caused by the compiler trying to reference deleted copy constructor of `MoveOnly` type. This error does not make much sense to me, because there is no reason to copy anything here instead of moving. `/std:c++14`, `/std:c++17`, `/std:c++latest` do not help.  Also the fact the gcc and clang handle the code correctly makes me suspicious about msvc 2017 compiler.

Update:

After [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk) found what the problem is, I tried using other containers in place of `unordered_map` and the code only compiles with `vector`.

Comment: [Compiles](http://rextester.com/TPDG66566) with RexTester's copy of VC2017

Comment: @IgorTandetnik please check this test:
https://godbolt.org/g/rxU6wF
that uses newer compiler (19.10.25017 vs 19.00.23506)

Comment: As a workaround, does `template<class M>size_t operator()(M&&)const{return 0;}` fix it?

Comment: Or, manualy mark `MoveOnly(MoveOnly&&) = default;` and `operator=` as noexcept?

Comment: @Yakk marking everything as `noexcept` well as adding this `operator()` does not help:

https://godbolt.org/g/mzJXVm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem seems to be this:

```
static_assert( noexcept(std::unordered_map<MoveOnly, int, Hasher>( std::declval<std::unordered_map<MoveOnly, int, Hasher>&&>())), "");
```

Your compiler doesn't think `std::unordered_map<MoveOnly, int, Hasher>` can be `noexcept` move-constructed.

Then, the paranoid `std::vector` implementation that MSVC 2017 ships with falls back on *copying* elements to generate a strong exception guarantee on vector resize.

Copying is obviously not possible.

Now the same is true of `std::unordered_map<int, int>` -- MSVC thinks that moving it *also* risks throwing exceptions; I believe nothing you can do with the key or hash type can possibly make the move constructor of `unordered_map` exception-safe.

There is no good reason for `unordered_map(unordered_map&&)` to *not* be `noexcept`.  I am uncertain if the standard permits it or mandates it, or if it is a bug in the compiler; if the standard mandates it to be `noexcept(false)`, then the standard has a defect.

You can work around this by storing a vector of `unique_ptr`s.  Or write an exception-eating `value_ptr` with fewer changes to your code:

```
template<class T>
struct value_ptr {
    std::unique_ptr<T> raw;
    value_ptr() noexcept(true)
    {
      try {
        raw = std::make_unique<T>();
      } catch (...) {}
    }
    template<class T0, class...Ts,
        std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<value_ptr, std::decay_t<T0>>{}, bool> =true
    >
    value_ptr(T0&& t0, Ts&&...ts) noexcept(true)
    {
      try {
        raw=std::make_unique<T>( std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... )
      } catch(...) {}
    }
    value_ptr(value_ptr&& o)noexcept(true)=default;
    value_ptr(value_ptr const& o)noexcept(true)
    { try {
      if (o.raw)
        raw = std::make_unique<T>(*o.raw);
      }catch(...){}
    }
    value_ptr& operator=(value_ptr&& o)noexcept(true)=default;
    value_ptr& operator=(value_ptr const& o)noexcept(true)
    { try {
      if (o.raw)
        raw = std::make_unique<T>(*o.raw);
      }catch(...){}
      return *this;
    }
    T* operator->() const { return raw.get(); }
    T& operator*() const { return *raw; }
    explicit operator bool() const { return (bool)raw; }
};
```

Here is my test harness:

```
template<class M>
void test_M() {
  static_assert( noexcept(M( std::declval<M&&>())), "");
  std::vector < M > test;
  test.emplace_back();

}
void foo()
{
  using M0=value_ptr<std::unordered_map<MoveOnly, int, Hasher>>;
  using M1=std::unique_ptr<std::unordered_map<MoveOnly, int, Hasher>>;
  test_M<M0>();
  test_M<M1>();
}
```

Comment: Wow! That is indeed paranoia! Thank you very much for looking into it. I was able to fix the error with simple wrapper over my `unordered_map` that declares move constructor as `noexcept`:

`struct ParanoiaFix
{
   ParanoiaFix()noexcept {};
   ParanoiaFix(ParanoiaFix&& rhs)noexcept : 
   val(std::move(rhs.val))
   {
   }
    std::unordered_map<MoveOnly, int, Hasher> val;
};
std::vector < ParanoiaFix > test;
`

Comment: Is this a bug in the compiler or in Dinkumware? (Spit.) Have you reported this to Microsoft VC++ people? They are good about responding to and fixing bugs.

Comment: @JiveDadson I would certainly report this to MSFT because to me this is a nonsense. It looks like now I need to mark all my constructors as `noexcept` or STL containers will resort to copies instead of moves. Do you know the best way to report the compiler issue?

Comment: @Egor - The best way?  Probably not. But I have had success posting to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vcgenera

Comment: @Egor - I did it. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f6332282-45e7-4c60-a918-00c8adeaeb71/move-ctor-not-noexcept-woe-from-stackoverflow?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: @egor marking move ctors as noexcept or vector copies is both in agreement with the standard and done on purpose by msft.  The bug here is that unordered map fails to have a noexcept move ctor.  Well and that msft introduced this improved standard compliance breaking change with no way to say "no thanks".

Comment: @Yakk I updated the title. I also tried other containers and the code only compiles with vector.