# MSVC requiring an explicit defaulted move constructor with vector and map

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I've run into an interesting issue with MSVC. The following code does not compile with MSVC:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct S {
    explicit S(const std::string&);

    // S(S&&) = default;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> a;
    std::string s;
};

std::vector<S> foo() {
    std::vector<S> s;
    s.emplace_back("hello");
    s.emplace_back("world");
    return s;
}
```

https://www.godbolt.ms/z/pQnKwD

However, it does compile when either a defaulted move constructor is provided, or *either* the `vector` or the `unordered_map` are commented out. Commenting out the `emplace_back` statements also "solves" the problem. The problem does not occur with GCC or Clang, interestingly (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4e5590bd63c0de0).

What's going on here?

Comment: Which version of MSVC/cl?

Comment: My version is 15.9.6 (cl 19.16), though apparently it's also a problem with the latest preview (and clang-cl).

Comment: I get a linker error when using this bit of code.

Comment: I maybe wrong, but shouldn't this be `explicit S(const std::string&);` this instead `explicit S(const std::string&){}`.

Comment: @JoeyMallone: obviously, as the `explicit` ctor is only declared. But the complaint was that this doesn't even compile. It does compile for you?

Comment: Yes, but I was testing on a different configuration - Ubuntu with `gcc 7.3.0`.

Comment: @JoeyMallone if you want it to link, then sure. You'd also need a `main` function, too. I left it out because it wasn't directly interesting to the problem I was having, though.

Comment: I added a `main()` also. And can compile, link and run this bit of code, albeit with `gcc 7.3.0`.

Comment: Can you verify that this is not a problem with the `noexcept` shenanigans that MSVC has had for ages with (not-`noexcept`) moveable types in vectors? E.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604029/move-constructors-of-stl-containers-in-msvc-2017-are-not-marked-as-noexcept)? It sounds very much like that issue, just in a different form...

Comment: @MaxLanghof I don't think it is. For one, `std::unique_ptr<T>` is noexcept-moveable, and so a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` should be fine - there is only one member that's not noexcept-moveable. `std::unordered_map` is not noexcept-moveable, of course, so `S` is not noexcept-moveable. Except when you default the move constructor, in which case a `static_assert` still says it's not noexcept-moveable, but suddenly the `vector` works. It also works, I've discovered, when adding an (unused) `std::unique_ptr` member to `S`. Basically I'm just trying to work out _why_ all of this is happening.

Comment: ... having said that, I went looking based on what you said and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53168836/does-visual-studio-2017-need-an-explicit-move-constructor-declaration (which I'm ashamed I didn't find before), which does appear to be the same problem.